# iOS : Date conversion results in wrong date

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have done this several times before with several formats. Cannot understand what am overlooking here! Date conversion cannot be that hard! :) But seems like it's bothering too much.
Am getting a string like this:
**Aug  9 2013 06:44:01:950AM**

Am trying to convert it to date with this code:

```
[Date_Converter getDateFromString:date withFormat:@"MMM dd YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSSa"]
```

And in **DateConverter.m**

```
+(NSDate *) getDateFromString:(NSString *) strDate
                   withFormat:(NSString *) format {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:format];
    //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSDate *dateFromStr = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
    return dateFromStr;
}
```

The `NSDate` return value am getting from the above method is this!
**2013-01-04 19:14:01 +0000**

for the input date
**Aug  9 2013 06:44:01:950AM**

How can this be? I have used the same method several times for various other formats of date. Please help. What am I overlooking here?

**UPDATE**
Changed the format to

```
[Date_Converter getDateFromString : date
       withFormat : @"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"];
```

but it still returns null. Kindly help.

**WHAT HELPED FINALLY**
Adding
    [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
to date conversion as @MartinR suggested below!

Comment: Are you using NSLog to print date?

Comment: Use `yyyy`, not `YYYY`. And use `hh`, not `HH`. By the way, are you stuck with that date format, or can you change it to use a more standard format?

Comment: It comes from another system over which I have no control. So, am stuck. Let me try that @Rob . Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Rob ! your answer helped me! can you please post it as answer so I can mark it right? you were the first to reply right!

Comment: @Jean Thanks. Martin R posted [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18148565/1271826), so you should feel free to accept his. No offense will be taken.

Comment: @Rob, I tried the format @"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa" -> it still returns null. Any guidance please?

Comment: @Jean When I use `@"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"` on `@"Aug 9 2013 06:44:01:950AM"`, it works fine for me. I tried on iOS 5.0 and 6.1, and it works on both. Are you sure it's not something else? The only other thing would be the localization settings on your device, but I first want to make sure we're 100% sure on the two strings, the format string and the actual date string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two errors in your date format:

- The correct format for years is `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.
- The format for the 12-hour AM/PM time is `hh`, not `HH`.

**UPDATE:** In addition, to avoid dependencies on the current locale, add

```
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

if you have a fixed input format which uses the english month names/abbreviations.

Comment: I tried the format @"MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa" -> it still returns null. Any guidance please?

Comment: @Jean: It could be a locale problem. Try adding `[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];` as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18258115/1187415 and see if it helps.

Comment: yes, looks like it is that! Works now once I added the initwithlocaleidentifier ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check this..

```
  NSString *date = @"Aug 9 2013 06:44:01:950AM"; 

 [Date_Converter getDateFromString:date withFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa"];//only you need to lower the char(yyyy) and it will be fine .
```

And Here is output

```
date = 2013-08-09 00:44:01 +0000
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In objective c for `NSDate` if you did not set the `setTimeZone`, `NSDate` will take default timezone as localTimeZone. so if you need to get the exact date which you give as `NSString` string format, you need to setTimeZone as UTC. Follow the sample code, I guess it will be helpful for you.

```
NSDateFormatter *loacalformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[loacalformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *localDate =[loacalformatter dateFromString:@"2013-01-04 19:14:01"];
NSLog(@"localDate :%@",localDate);


NSDateFormatter *UTCformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[UTCformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[UTCformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *UTCDate =[UTCformatter dateFromString:@"2013-01-04 19:14:01"];
NSLog(@"UTCDate :%@",UTCDate);
```

**UTCDate :2013-01-04 19:14:01 +0000 (GMT+00:00)**

Comment: While this is an interesting observation, the OP's issue was that the input date was "Aug 9 2013" and the result was "2013-01-04"! That's not a time zone problem. There was a more fundamental issue in his date format string.

Comment: Yeah, using YYYY seems to muck up dates badly.