# Getting Null from NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert a String into NSDate, but I am getting Null.

Sample String Input is = 8/8/2013 12:32:22 PM

Code:

```
[self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"Date %@", [[communications objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"dateUpdated"]);
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [self.dateFormat dateFromString:[[communications objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"dateUpdated"]];
NSLog(@"Date from NSDate %@", [self.dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Sample NSLog Output

```
2013-08-15 13:01:59.409 HD[478:907] Date 8/8/2013 12:32:22 PM
2013-08-15 13:01:59.412 HD[478:907] Date from NSDate (null)  
2013-08-15 13:01:59.418 HD[478:907] Date 8/12/2013 9:45:18 AM
2013-08-15 13:01:59.419 HD[478:907] Date from NSDate (null)
2013-08-15 13:01:59.421 HD[478:907] Date 8/12/2013 9:45:20 AM
2013-08-15 13:01:59.423 HD[478:907] Date from NSDate (null)
2013-08-15 13:01:59.430 HD[478:907] Date 8/12/2013 4:10:49 PM
2013-08-15 13:01:59.431 HD[478:907] Date from NSDate (null)
```

Note: What's really strange is that if I run the same code on Simulator it works fine and most devices. For some reason, if I run it on a handful of devices that are all up to date, it returns null...

Comment: Has your dateFormatter been intialized? this line is also superfluous in the context of your method `NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];` because an allocated NSDate will be returned from the dateFromString method

Comment: Just ran your code and it works... @JustinAmberson is right make sure your date formatter has been intialized.

Comment: my DateFormatter is initilized.

Comment: totally weird, something to do with some previous SDKs? Do you know which version of iOS it's not reliable on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably locale-dependent, but with

```
[self.dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

it should work on all devices.

Comment: THIS WAS IT! X_X I wouldn't have got this without your help... THANK YOU. If you wouldn't mind, could you give me a brief summary on why this fixed the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes, then report back:

```
[self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"Date %@", [[communications objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"dateUpdated"]);
NSDate *date = [self.dateFormat dateFromString:[[communications objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"dateUpdated"]];
NSLog(@"Date from NSDate %@", [self.dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

Also make sure

```
if (!self.dateFormat) {
    self.dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Yea it didn't work. Please read the edit. For some reason it works in Sim, but not some devices.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to check if your code is working in single pieces. For instance, try to see the NSString that is going to be used in -dateFromString: method is in the desired format. Also, in order to check if your code is working, you're reverting the operation from NSDate to NSString.

I have tried the following code and it works well. So definitely, your error is somewhere else, but not in the date format itself. Check also if your NSDateFormatter was properly initilized.

```
NSString *dateString = @"8/8/2013 12:32:22 PM";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```