# NSDate dateFromString: returns null

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've seen many posts on this topic but I can't resolve mine/ I guess I have an issue in my format date but I don't know which one.

```
dateStr = @"Thu, 19 Dec 2013 13:33:58 +0000" // My string I want to convert
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM y HH:m:s Z"]; // Here might be the issue
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr]);
```

And the output is :

```
2014-04-02 16:51:02.871 MyApp[3957:60b] Date: (null)
```

I tried some differents format but I always get null NSDate.

I retrieve the strings from Dropbox API, in the documentation it says that the format is :

```
"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z" with strftime or strptime
```

Thanks

Comment: for the year try "yyyy" instead only one "y"

Comment: Can you get the dates from dropbox in a non-string format?

Comment: Your date conversion works for me (in the iOS Simulator) without problems, so it might be a locale problem. Try setting a POSIX locale as (for example) shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18258115/1187415 (there are other similar answers as well).

Comment: OK try `"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`
 was the solution, thanks @MartinR

Comment: @BoilingLime: You are welcome! (So we can close this as a duplicate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Null from NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257842/getting-null-from-nsdateformatter)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that NSDate conversion of Dropbox "modified" file date metadata works only for well known locales, so I used this naive method

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale: [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"]];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
    NSDate *dateModified = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dropboxDictionay[@"modified"]];
   [dateFormatter setLocale:  [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]]]; 
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
myLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateModified];
```

and works for me ...

Dimitris